# Можно ли каким-либо методом упростить мой алгоритм поиска массива внутри массива?

Tags: javascript

Во время изучения JS заметил, что в нем нет толкового встроенного поиска массива внутри другого массива, поэтому на скорую руку набросал сам алгоритм и упростил его в пределах своих возможностей. Собственно, можно ли его еще упростить или может есть другой путь решения этой задачи?

```
Array.prototype.array_in_array = function(array)
    {
        for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
            var flag = true;
            if(this[i].length != array.length)
                continue;
            for(var j = 0;j < this[i].length;j++)
            {
                if(this[i][j] != array[j])
                {
                    flag=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Логичнее использовать строгое равенство.
2. Индекс был бы полезнее, чем bool.
3. Скобки в джаваскрипте не случайно принято ставить по-другому.

А код я бы написал так:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfSubArray = function (a) {
  Q: for (var q=0; q<this.length; ++q) {
    if (this[q] === a) {
      return q;
    }

    if (this[q].length === a.length) {
      for (var w=0; w<a.length; ++w) {
        if (this[q][w] !== a[w]) {
          continue Q;
        }
      }

      return q;
    }
  }

  return -1;
};
```

Comment: 1. `==` работает точно так же как и `===`, совсем нет разницы, если типы обоих операндов одинаковы, не везде есть смысл писать строгое равно. 2. `this[q] === a` будет выполняться только в очень редких случаях, потому что два объекта никогда не равны, если их ссылки не ссылаются на один и тот же элемент.

Comment: 1.1. А почему собственно они должны оказаться одинаковыми? 1.2. Как раз при одинаковых и имеет смысл использовать `===`. А если хочешь получить приведение, то `==`. 2. А если его из этого массива и достали?

Comment: @Rolandius, вас не смущает, что `({}) == '[object Object]'`?

Comment: 1. Я знаю, как работает `==`, а как работает `===`, и я знаю, @dzhioev, _почему_ ({}) == '[object Object]'. Прошу еще раз прочитать моё сообщение и заметить, что там написано: "**не везде** есть смысл писать строгое равно"; поясню, это значит, что не надо пихать его _везде_, прошу прощения, что неправильно выразил свою мысль. Вопрос не в работе этих операторов, пустой разговор. 2. Плохой пример. Какой смысл искать в массиве элемент, который из этого массива же и достали, разве мы не знаем тогда достоверно, что он там есть?

Comment: @Rolandius, так я же индекс возвращаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.existArrayInArray = function (pattern) {
 var self = this
 return !!~self.map(function (el) {
   return el.join('')  
 }).indexOf(pattern.join(''))
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2g4xdq44/

Perl-style
Проверки массив на вход пришёл или нет можете осуществить сами (массив ли элемент? на входе пришёл массив?)

Comment: Наверное, стоит чуть объяснить. [1,2,3].join('') вернёт строку '123', поэтому поиск просто осуществляется линейно по массиву. indexOf возвращает либо -1 (если не нашёл), либо индекс, где есть совпадение. ~ делает побитовый сдвиг, то есть -1 превращается в 0, а индекс чуть сдвигается, !! приводит к boolean и получается, что если не нашли (-1), то false, иначе true.

Comment: `[[1,2,3,4,5]].existArrayInArray([12,345])` - результат `true`. Это даже не говоря о том, что для объектов не работает.

Comment: Ок, сделать join("#") или что хочешь придумать. Да, можно придумать случаи, когда работать не будет и твой вариант с двумя циклами будет единственным. И почему это для объектов должно работать? Вопрос был задан о массивах. Для объектов дописывается по аналогии.